# PyQgis Show a HTML frame in canvas from a plugin button

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, json, html

I am using PyQGIS to request a JSON and showing some data of that file, formatted according with some conditions, in a window in QGIS using a button in a plugin.

I have thought of using a HTML frame (not a map tip) with the formatted data or a modal window with a HTML frame, but I don't know if it is possible.

Is it possible to show a HTML frame in canvas using PyQGIS?

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps someone, this can be done using QWebEngineView from Qt.